# Makefile always call all even with target

Tags: makefile

Okay, I think I'm missing something in my makefile and it's causing me headaches. In my local build I call it with `"dev:"` and it does the dev target; Great, but I also want it to always do the `"all:"` target. When I call `make dev` it runs the dev but not the all, is there a terminology fail here?

here is my makefile

```
BUILD="build/"
STATIC="static/"
APP_NAME="Open World"

all:
    # Remove the current build folder
    rm -rf ${BUILD}

    # Create the build directory
    mkdir -p ${BUILD}

dev:
    all
    dev=${STATIC}dev

    echo "Doing DEVELOPMENT build"

    # Copy the package.json
    cp ${dev}package.json ${BUILD}

prod:
    echo "production"
```

Comment: Don't forget the `.PHONY` target.

Comment: "all" is just a convention.  It has absolutely no special meaning to make.  You could have no "all" target, or you could put "all" at the end of your makefile (where it wouldn't be invoked unless you specifically ran `make all`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default (first) target is only run if no target is explicitly given. If you want it to run when another target is given then you need to make it a dependency of that target.

```
dev: all
```

Comment: I knew it would be something totally stupid like this.. Thanks!